# C++ Cast double to char and replace into std::array

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

For RAM optimization purpose, I need to store my data as a `std::array<char, N>` where N is the "templated size_t" size of the array.
I need to manage a huge amount of "Line" objects that contain any kind of data (numerical and char).

So my Line class is:

```
template<size_t NByte>
class Line {
public:
  Line (std::array<char, NByte> data, std::vector<size_t> offset) :
      _data(data), _offset(offset) {}

  template<typename T>
  T getValue (const size_t& index) const {
    return *reinterpret_cast<const T*>(_data.data() + _offset[index]);
  }

  template<typename T>
  void setValue (const size_t& index, const T value) const {
    char * new_value = const_cast<char *>(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&value));
    std::move(new_value, new_value + sizeof(T), const_cast<char *>(_data.data() + _offset[index]));
  }

private:
  std::array<char, NByte> _data;
  std::vector<size_t> _offset;
};
```

My questions are:

- Is there a better way to do the setter and getter function?
- Is this robust against memory leak?
- Is there any problem to use this code in production/release?

**Edit:** The question behind those is: Is there any other way to work with binary data in memory and provide "human understandable" interface for final user through setter and getter?

Comment: It seems your `getValue` and `setValue` functions could be replaced by a couple of `operator[]` overloads. Won't help with making the code in the function "better" though. On the other hand now you have learned the downside of optimized code: It's usually horrible.

Comment: By the way, if the code is working and you just want a "review" of it (which seems to be what you want), then there is http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Miss cliking from my side :-(

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I'm quite new to programming world and didn't know  http://codereview.stackexchange.com. I'll move my question to it. Thanks for the advise! Is there a way to move it from SO?

Comment: @Peter: There are no comma operators here, the three-argument `std::move` function is being called.  And I can't see any addresses being stored anywhere.  The pointers are being used as iterators, which is legal.  The `const_cast` in the `new_value` initializer is bogus.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any problem in using this code in production/release?

Yes, this code is platform-dependent.

The data will be stored differently in Big-Endian platforms and in Little-Endian platforms.

If your're counting on two systems communicating with each other (transmitting and receiving this data), then you will have to make sure that both sides use platforms of the same Endianness.

Comment: Thanks! However, our code will run on a known platforms and will not communicate externally. It will read/write the data into file.

Comment: @Elendil: And how can you be sure that this file won't be passed around to some opposite-endianness system at some point?

Comment: This because its a requirement of our data pipeline: we know the exact architecture of the data center. And this code will never run out side of those data center.